# Is there a way to have hidden content of a page slide UP into page? jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, this is what I'm trying to do. I have content, a form, a the bottom of my page, with its display set to none. What I want to do, is when someone clicks an up arrow, the image icon, the whole form will slide UP into view, and become visible, while if they click the arrow again, it will return the form to slide back down and also set its display back to none. This is what I have so far.

```
<div class="hidden_panel_wrapper">
<div class="hidden_panel_icon"> <img id="hidden_panel_icon" src="thumbnails/up_arrow.png"> </div>
<div class="hidden_panel hide" id="hidden_panel">
<div class="hidden_panel_form">
<form name="newsletter_subscribe" method="post" action="subscribe_success.php">
<input class="text_input" type="email" placeholder="Type E-Mail Address" name="email">
<input type="submit" class="button_input" value="Subscribe To Our Newsletter">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So I know that to use slide toggle, slidedown will bring elements into view, but i cant figure out how to slideUP and bring an element into view. I looked around at jquery animate, couldn't really figured it out, and i also just looked at setting new styles via javascript (object.style.top="-200px" but that didnt really work. To be simple, I need a slidetoggle, but so it my content will slide UP into view, and DOWN back to display="none". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you are wanting. http://jsfiddle.net/bR6Fs/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".caption").hide();
});
  var show = function() {
    $(".caption").slideUp(500);
  };  
  var hide = function() {
    $(".caption").slideDown(500);
  };
      $(".featured-image").hover(hide, show);
```

Comment: Well, its what I want, but its actullythe exact opposite. I want the slideup to be making the content appear, and the slidedown to be the function that slides it down out of the page.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle link provided. I changed the names around.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animate plus some creativity should work.  You'll have to tweak some parts of this based on the kind of animation you want and what you know about where you want it to go, but the framework should work.

The script:

```
//get height of window
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
//difference between window height and desired distance from top, e.g. 200px
var moveDistance = windowHeight - 200;
$('.hidden_panel_wrapper').css({'top' : moveDistance+'px', 'display' : 'block'});
$('.hidden_panel_wrapper').animate({top:0});
```

Then to slide it out it's basically the reverse:

```
//get height of window
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
//difference between window height and desired distance from top, e.g. 200px
var moveDistance = windowHeight - 200;
$('.hidden_panel_wrapper').animate({top:moveDistance}).css('display' : 'none');
```

That said, there are a number of jQuery addons that you can Google for if you're going to be doing a lot of animation and want a bigger toolkit for prebuilt functions.